# Token replace strings using '{}' rather than '%s' in String.format

Tags: java

String.format requires the placeholder strings to be `%s`. I am using slf4j which uses `{}` as its placeholder string.

Is there anything in the JDK that will allow me to do a String.format using `{}` as a placeholder string?

As noted in the comments below, there is `MessageFormat.format()` but this requires that I put the index between the brackets. eg. `{0}`.

Comment: Please provide the code that handles the logging/formatting, that you have written up until now.

Comment: Do what exactly yourself? Sounds like you only need to change your strings containing the parameter placeholders. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Log4j could be worth a look at.

Comment: 1. Don't write your own logging framework. 2. There's java.text.MessageFormat

Answer (score 0):

1) You cannot avoid the use of "%" based placeholders in Formatter. So Formatter/Formattable is not the solution.

2) If you need an method, replacing the {} placeholders with parameter values, it is easy to implement yourself.

```
public static String insertPlaceholders(String template, Object... args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        return template;
    }
    // best guess for capacity
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(template.length() + args.length * 8);
    int index = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    while (index < args.length) {
        final int p = template.indexOf("{}", offset);
        if (p < 0) {
            break;
        }
        sb.append(template, offset, p);
        sb.append(args[index]);
        offset = p + 2;
        ++index;
    }
    sb.append(template, offset, template.length());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Unit test:

```
@Test
public void testInsertPlaceholders() {
    assertSame("Test", StringUtils.insertPlaceholders("Test"));
    assertEquals("Test", StringUtils.insertPlaceholders("Test", 1));
    assertEquals("Test 2", StringUtils.insertPlaceholders("Test {}", 2));
    assertEquals("Test 3 {}", StringUtils.insertPlaceholders("Test {} {}", 3));
    assertEquals("Hello World!", StringUtils.insertPlaceholders("Hello {}!", "World"));
}
```